# Is it possible to draw an isosceles triangle with a compass and a ruler?

Tags: euclidean-geometry

Is it possible to draw an isosceles triangle with a compass and a ruler?
 The ruler is not marked, the two legs of the compass cannot leave the paper, and the two points on the plane are known.

**I mean the two points at the base of the isosceles triangle are already given. The legs of the isosceles triangle are not given. **

First draw a circle at one point, with the legs of the compass not leaving the paper, drag to another point, and then draw a second circle?

Comment: To my understanding, if the two legs of the compass cannot leave the paper, you can only draw one circle. Also, which two points are known?

Comment: I think OP means "you cannot lift the compass up".

Comment: Means the same thing.  If the positioning of the compass cannot be changed, how can you ever draw more than one circle?

Comment: @CalvinLin what does "not lifting up the compass" mean, materially, if not what I said?

Comment: @Gae.S. I was trying to express that we we have a "collapsible compass". IE could use the compass via drawing arc/circles at multiple different centers, but cannot "bring along the distance draw to another circle with a distinct center".  (I subsequantly realized we only need 1 circle to achieve this)

Comment: @CalvinLin Ah, I see the intention now. Quite a questionable exercise.

Comment: What do "the two points" refer to?  Are you requiring that these two points be vertices of the triangle?  Maybe you are even requiring that the two points be opposite the equal sides?

Comment: What is the "waist" of an isosceles triangle?

Comment: Move the compass to one of the given points. Make its aperture larger than half of the given segment. For example, the same as the given segment is larger than half of it. If the side of the isosceles triangle were given make it of that size. Draw a circle. Then move the compass to the  other given point and without changing the aperture. Draw a circle. The two circles intersect at two points. Draw, with the ruler then lines joining these points to the two given points. Two triangles will appear, which are two solutions.

Comment: Sorry.  I mean the two points at the base of the isosceles triangle are already given.

Comment: Your stipulation about the 2 legs of the compass not leaving the paper is highly confusing. You can easily do this with a standard straight-edge and compass construction, by constructing the perpendicular bisector of the given line segment (the two given points of the base). Any point on that bisector wil be the apex of an isosceles triangle. But if you can't lift the compass up from one point and put it down on another, you can only make concentric circles, and I don't see a way to use that. Please be more precise about what you expect.

Comment: The legs of the isosceles triangle are not given.

Comment: @lulu  The legs of the isosceles triangle are not given.

Comment: @Deepak First draw a circle at one point, with the legs of the compass not leaving the paper, drag to another point, and then draw a second circle?

Comment: @CalvinLin n  First draw a circle at one point, with the legs of the compass not leaving the paper, drag to another point, and then draw a second circle?